# Does this look like green pepper or red pepper plants?

Tags: bell-peppers

My hubby and I are NOT gardeners. Are these peppers (bell pepper) or weeds?

Hate to be watering weeds lol
[image: pepper?]

Answer (score 4):

Look like coles - cabbage, kohlrabi, broccoli ,brussel sprouts, kale, etc.They need to grow before I could tell them apart; maybe another answer will be more definite.

Comment: I agree they look like brassicas but they won't grow well crowded into a pot like that. They should have been transplanted out and at least a foot apart, but they are probably too big to successfully transplant them now. It is hard to tell young brassica plants apart, because cabbage, cauliflower, broccoli, and sprouts are actually exactly the same plant species, but they have been selected (by humans) to grow in different shapes and sizes.

Comment: As elongated as they are, they look rather like *Brassica rapa* aka oilseed rape/canola, and so in this context, probably a weed.

Comment: Definitely not peppers. :) I agree that they look like something in the Cabbage family, whether or not in the Brassica genus. Looks similar to arugula and radishes.